# Changing height of parent element messes up whole webpage

Tags: html, css

**Here is my HTML**

```
<body>
    <script src="" async defer>
    </script>
    <div class="topBar">
        <div class="dropdowns">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="Homepage.html">Home Page</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="Page2.html">Page 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="Page3.html">Page 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="Page4.html">Page 4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="sunset-img" src="C:image.jpg" alt="img error">
        <div class="myName">
            TEST
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Here is my CSS**

```
/*
whole page -----------------------------------------
*/
body {
    background-color:bisque;
    margin:0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}


/*
Top bar -----------------------------------------
*/
.topBar {
    background-color: gray;
  }

.dropdowns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;

}   
 
  
.dropdown {
    padding: 20px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    
    
 
  }
  
.dropdown > a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}


/*
Main content -----------------------------------------
*/

.container{
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


#sunset-img {
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}


.myName{
    border: solid 10px;
    position: absolute;
    color:rgb(0, 75, 25);
}
```

And I am using Google Chrome if that matters

---

My problem is that I messed up and in the css where is says

```
.container{
    height: auto; 
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I want height to be auto so it can be based of the width(of the webpage). The problem is when I do this my container div moves to the very top  of the page and even extends even beyond the page so I only see the lower part. It does not do this when I make width auto and height 100vh.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There several ways to do what you intend (if I understand well).

That's one, tell me if it's ok for you

```css
body {
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.topBar {
  background-color: gray;
}

.dropdowns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dropdown {
  padding: 20px;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

.dropdown>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1280/1024");
  background-size: cover;
}

#sunset-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.myName {
  border: solid 10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(0, 75, 25);
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div class="dropdowns">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="Homepage.html">Home Page</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="Page2.html">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="Page3.html">Page 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="Page4.html">Page 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="myName">
    TEST
  </div>
</div>
```